# After upgrading my application from Angular 14 to 16, I am getting 100's of errors in npm packages that I have used

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-ivy

I upgraded my angular application from v14 to v16.
Since there were so many peer dependencies I used --force flag to upgrade.
Now when I compile getting so many errors as shown below in screenshot.

[Errors look like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uL30.png)

What is compatible to Angular IVY. And how to check for any package if it is Angular IVY compatible or not?

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4300",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~16.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "12.1.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.4",
    "@ngx-formly/bootstrap": "5.5.10",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^5.10.8",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "@uirouter/core": "^6.0.7",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "angular-datatables": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-formly": "^8.4.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.25",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.11.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-idletimer": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng": "0.0.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^12.0.3",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.5.2",
    "ngx-currency-input": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.1.1",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.13.5",
    "xlsx-js-style": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.28",
    "angular-file": "^3.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.6",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` so we know which versions of the packages you are using? In general all libraries which were built with Angular v13 or later have support for Ivy, and packages which were built with Angular v11 or earlier are unlikely to have Ivy support. Also please clarify your question. If a package throws such errors, it is obviously not compatible with Ivy. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Thanks for adding the `package.json`. I just checked the first dependency from the error message `@ng-select/ng-select`, you are using a very old version. You should update this package to version  11.x. In general, you need to update your dependencies. It might also happen that there is a dependency where no update to Ivy is available, in this case you need to approach the author of the package.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is, you have to check all your third party libraries compatibility/support to angular 16. This might feel painfully slow but go one by one. Once done more often than not when you do npm install, it works (dont force it). if it doesnt, check what error message says.
Also use **npm outdated** to find out the list of outdated dependencies.
After that use the official guidelines (https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=14.0-16.0) that will guide you through what else needs to change. A global search for whats deprecated in your project would help.

Answer (score 0):

just delete your node modules and .angular folders and run command in terminal

```
npm i --force
```

this solved everything for me...
comment if not worked

Comment: This will not fix the issue. Apparently the author uses very old dependency versions and the error is accurate.

Comment: You use force flag and you will miss all the compatibility issues that will cause you more pain the future. Best is to solve all the issues/errors one by one